# ssh, is better to use -X or -Y?

Tags: ssh, x11

Simple question: for security is more safe to use `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`?
As I know ssh -Y is X11Trusted, so no more controls are made, so is better to use -X for security reason.
What did you think?
I usually use -Y, because if I use the -X options I read this message when I did ssh on target machine.

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated
```

I connect a machine over the lan.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give some context. What kind of machine are you connecting to? Is this over the internet or a local network? What level of security do you require?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answer by myself.
Probably the `ssh -X` option is the more secure.
Because require two type of authentication: the ssh(password, kerberos, or public key) and the x11(xauth, xhost) authentication.
When we use `ssh -Y` which is called "trusted" we trust the host and we bypass the X11 auth so we don't need to use the command xhost.
So in my opinion `ssh -X` is more safe, there is only one problem: with the latest version of ssh seems to give this problem
I did

```
\ssh -vvv  -X myhost
```

and I get those two errors

```
Warning: untrusted X11 forwarding setup failed: xauth key data not generated

debug2: client_x11_get_proto: xauth command: /usr/bin/xauth -f /tmp/ssh-KYHfkmGN25fa/xauthfile generate :0.0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 2>/dev/null
```

when I try to run xauth command directly give me this error

```
/usr/bin/xauth -f /tmp/ssh-KYHfkmGN25fa/xauthfile generate :0.0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /tmp/ssh-KYHfkmGN25fa/xauthfile
```

Workaround: edit ssh_config and enabled those lines

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

ssh -X now works fine but there is only one problem
I have try to disable access

```
xhost -
```

and running ssh -X still accept the host! So I think that
ForwardX11Trusted yes override         ForwardX11 yes

Editing ssh_config

```
Host *
    ForwardAgent yes
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted no
```

and ssh -X don't work.
So the problem is still open.

Comment: "the problem is still open" = not an answer?

Comment: Can be an answer, but the problem (of ssh) is still open. I have tried -Y and works fine, -X give a lot of problems and atm for me is not working.

Answer (score 2):

ssh's `-X` option enables X11 forwarding, and `-Y` enables trusted X11 forwarding.  The latter are not subject to the security controls of the `SECURITY` extension.

Ideally, you'd use `-X` to improve security.  However, if you use a Debian version of OpenSSH, the `-X` option contains this aside in the manual page:

> Debian-specific: X11 forwarding is not subjected to X11 SECURITY extension restrictions by default, because too many programs currently crash in this mode.  Set the ForwardX11Trusted option to “no” to restore the upstream behaviour.  This may change in future depending on client-side improvements.

Therefore, disabling trusted forwarding is not really a practical choice, and if you'd like your programs to actually work, you'll need to use a trusted forwarding.  On Debian, `-X` does this; `-Y` does it on all systems.